# Transfer in Dubai from arrivals to departures

Tags: transit, dubai

Hello I'm arriving in Dubai International Terminal 3 on QF8002 from London Heathrow I'm leaving on QF8430 to Brisbane, could you please advise whereabouts I need to go and how long is it likely to take.  I have 2 hours but dont walk quickly

Comment: Please, ask the staff on the plane as you fly (as well as any answers here). We did that for transiting through Abu Dhabi with an infant and they made sure to give us directions and a pushchair ready when we left the plane, and may be able to give you extra help.

Comment: Even better, contact the airline _now_, before you depart, to let them know you'll need a wheel chair/push chair or motorized transport to get from gate to gate. They'll be sure to arrange something for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on one ticket, there should be no problem. But it’s a long walk, feels like half a mile.
If you have two separate tickets, it will not work – you would have to pick up your luggage, immigrate, and check in again two hours before the next flight at the latest, which is impossible.

The exact path you have to walk it’s difficult to describe upfront, because it depends on which gate you come in and which gate your outgoing flight leaves, and whatever construction they potentially do currently in the airport and make you walk around.
There will be good signs in many places, and there are typically a lot of emirates people around, that you can ask for the right way. If you are able to walk 600 yards in one hour you’ll have no problems

Comment: If you can not walk 600 yards/meters, ask for assistance. Most/all airports have ways with either wheelchairs and someone to push it for you or transport you with motorized carts like golf carts.